# Momentjs in meteor- reactivity?

Tags: meteor, momentjs

Have been using https://github.com/acreeger/meteor-moment in meteor and it works well, however is there a way to make the output of moment reactive so that it counts up "3 seconds ago", "4 seconds ago", etc?

Comment: Not familiar with moment but [this is a general recommendation for how to handle reactive time](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/meteor-talk/6datYopVMrE/x63wPOECjGMJ).

Comment: Thanks for the replies everyone, I found a mrt package which does the job http://atmospherejs.com/package/livestamp

Comment: Your answer is out of date - that package is unsupported and incompatible with modern meteor.  You should mark user3374348 as the accepted answer.  His answer is out of date too, but all you have to do is change Deps to Tracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the replies everyone, I found a mrt package which does the job atmospherejs.com/package/livestamp

Answer (score 10):

Rather than using a new Session variable for each individual timer, I would create a single `Tracker.Dependency` which is flagged for changes every second (or perhaps every 10 seconds), then depend on this whenever you want to depend on the current time.

```js
var timeTick = new Tracker.Dependency();
Meteor.setInterval(function () {
  timeTick.changed();
}, 1000);

fromNowReactive = function (mmt) {
  timeTick.depend();
  return mmt.fromNow();
}

Template.example.helpers({
  example: function () {
    return fromNowReactive(moment().startOf('hour'));
  }
});
```

This is the approach taken by [`mizzao:timesync`](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/timesync), which is a useful package you can use if those `fromNow`s are based on server-side timestamps. One reason to not use client-generate timestamps is that these may be out of sync, resulting in strings like `5 seconds from now` for a post that was just made. `mizzao:timesync` allows server-generated timestamps to be used everywhere, and also groups different reactivity intervals together efficiently.

Comment: The Deps package name has been changed to Tracker.

Answer (score 2):

You can now use the package **copleykj:livestamp**. ([github](https://github.com/copleykj/meteor-livestamp/) | [atmosphere](https://atmospherejs.com/copleykj/livestamp))

Install it like this:

```
meteor add copleykj:livestamp
```

It has a dependency on momentjs:moment so it will bring that along automatically.  It installs a universal helper that is available anywhere and can be passed a date object.

You can use it in a template like this:

```
<li>Regular:   {{date}}          </li>
<li>Livestamp: {{livestamp date}}</li>
```

#### [Here's a working demo in MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/JRSxXtnszCqbbyb7K/Livestamp)

Comment: new to meteor, so the MeteorPad example was helpful

Comment: Meteorpad did not load for me, but this is - at this time - the best answer imo.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setTimeout` and `Session` to store your variable.

Something like this (in your lib file):

```
var updateTime = function () {
    var time = moment().startOf('hour').fromNow(); // 22 minutes ago
    Session.set('timeFromNow', time);
    setTimeout(updateTime, 60 * 1000); // 60 seconds
});
updateTime();
```

Then, in your template:

```
Template.t.timeFromNow = function () {
    return Session.get('timeFromNow');
}
```

When setTimeout triggered to update Session variable, the template is updated.