# How to make Meteor reactively update a "time since" string?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, meteor-helper

I want to implement a helper in my template that will display the time since a particular timestamp.

```
Template.postItem.helpers({
  timeSinceString: function(timestamp) {
    return moment(timestamp).fromNow();
  }
});
```

This works fine when it loads, but it doesn't update unless the template is reloaded. This is understandable because the `fromNow()` function isn't being tracked. How can I make sure that what the user sees is kept up-to-date?

Some examples:

- "5 hours ago"
- "a few seconds ago"
- "1 day ago"

Comment: Also see: [Momentjs in meteor- reactivity?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301149/momentjs-in-meteor-reactivity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found this package which made it super super simple: https://atmospherejs.com/copleykj/livestamp

Answer (score 1):

I take care of this using the [`mizzao:timesync`](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-timesync) package (which I wrote) in combination with [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/), which generates those specific strings.

`mizzao:timesync` is very useful since it allows you to use **server time** on the client by computing an NTP-style offset, so times are accurate even if the client time is wrong. It also efficiently groups together reactive timers for updating all timestamps on the screen.

An example is part of the [`mizzao:user-status`](https://atmospherejs.com/mizzao/user-status) demo: http://user-status.meteor.com/

Answer (score 0):

Load a function on rendered that updates a session variable:

```
Template.postItem.rendered(function() {
  setInterval(function() {
    Session.set('currentTime', moment());
  }, 1000); // Replace 1000 with your level of time detail
});

Template.postItem.helpers({
  timeSinceString: function(timestamp) {
    return Session.get('currentTime').from(moment(timestamp));
  }
});
```

Comment: For some reason I couldn't get this to work, but I found a package to take care of it. So thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

The [remcoder:chronos](https://atmospherejs.com/remcoder/chronos) package provides a very useful way to do exactly this. It defines a reactive time variable that updates itself.

Note: the default update interval is one second. I found that in practice this could suck up serious cpu cycles when many time variables are being displayed. For things that are changing rapidly (like a file upload progress meter) I use one second. For slower moving things I use 20 minutes.