# Reactive query depending on time

Tags: datetime, meteor, client

I have a collection which holds status messages. I want to show only those messages in the UI which have been changed within the last 5 seconds.

```
Template.myTemplate.helpers({
  results: function() {
    var name = Session.get('someSessionVar');
    var results = myCollection.find({
      name: name,
      createdAt: { // 5 seconds ago
        $gt: new Date().getTime() - 1000 * 5
      }
    }, {sort:{createdAt: 1}});
    return results;
  },
}
```

This basically works but it is only updating the query when `someSessionVar` changes. So it always shows the collection items which have been changed 5 seconds before the method is first executed or 5 seconds older then the time when `someSessionVar` changed.

I understand it only is reactive based on `someSessionVar`. My question is what's the best approach to filter the items as well by time? I could simply have an interval and write the current time into a session var. Is there a more elegant solution? I'm wondering if this is not adding unnecessary load to the client.

Comment: You might find this question useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25301149/momentjs-in-meteor-reactivity/25305221#25305221

Comment: @udondan You'll need to update a reactive variable (ReactiveVar, Session, etc.) every N seconds as shown in the linked answer and simply read it in your helper to cause it to periodically update. As N -> small, you'll get higher resolution at the cost of running your helper more times.